# FastAPI validation error on global retrieve

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I have an issue with FastAPI coupled with SQLModel and I don't understand why it doesn't work.
I have the following model:

```py
class DeckBase(SQLModel):
    name: str = Field(sa_column=Column(TEXT))

    # region Foreign keys
    owner_id: int = Field(foreign_key="player.id")
    # endregion Foreign keys

class Deck(DeckBase, table=True):
    id: int = Field(primary_key=True)

    # region Relationship (access to the foreign key model)
    owner: Player = Relationship(back_populates="decks")
    cards: List["Card"] = Relationship(back_populates="decks", link_model=DeckCards)  # ManyToMany
    # endregion Relationship (access to the foreign key model)
```

Here is the database representation:

[image: model]

I've also defined the following function to retrieve all the decks accordingly to the SQLModel documentation:

```py
@router.get("/", response_model=List[DeckRead])
async def read_all(offset: int = 0,
                   limit: int = Query(default=100, le=100),
                   db: Session = Depends(DbContext().get_db)):
    decks = db.execute(select(Deck).offset(offset).limit(limit)).all()
    return decks
```

With `DeckRead` being:

```py
class DeckRead(DeckBase):
    id: int
```

But when i'm calling the route, i get this error:

```
[2024-01-02 18:37:19] [ERROR   ] uvicorn.error: Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):

... (skipping the traceback)

fastapi.exceptions.ResponseValidationError: 3 validation errors:
  {'type': 'missing', 'loc': ('response', 0, 'name'), 'msg': 'Field required', 'input': (Deck(id=1, name='Fire deck', owner_id=1),), 'url': 'https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.5/v/missing'}
  {'type': 'missing', 'loc': ('response', 0, 'owner_id'), 'msg': 'Field required', 'input': (Deck(id=1, name='Fire deck', owner_id=1),), 'url': 'https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.5/v/missing'}
  {'type': 'missing', 'loc': ('response', 0, 'id'), 'msg': 'Field required', 'input': (Deck(id=1, name='Fire deck', owner_id=1),), 'url': 'https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.5/v/missing'}
```

Why does it not work?
Also, what bothers me is that doing the code below works fine:

```py
@router.get("/", response_model=List[DeckRead])
async def read_all(offset: int = 0,
                   limit: int = Query(default=100, le=100),
                   db: Session = Depends(DbContext().get_db)):
    decks = db.get(Deck, 1)
    return [decks]
```

It looks like the `all()` function returns me something that fastapi doesn't understand

Thanks!

Comment: While I haven't used SQLModel, Pydantic requires you to set `from_attributes` in the model config to be able to load properties from attributes (https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/config/#pydantic.config.ConfigDict.from_attributes) - this was previously named `orm_mode`, and I have no idea whether `SQLModel` has been updated to do this by default. I'd start by trying to set it explicitly (`model_config = ConfigDict(from_attributes=True)` on the model)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLModel uses a special [`exec` function](https://sqlmodel.tiangolo.com/tutorial/where/?h=exec#exec-the-statement) which wraps the underlying `execute` from SQLAlchemy. Simply changing your database call to

```py
decks = db.exec(select(Deck).offset(offset).limit(limit)).all()
```

should do the trick.

The reason for this is that SQLALchemy"s `execute` will return a list of tuples (since you can `select` more than one model), unless you add `.scalars()` to your query. SQLModel has a special function for the specific case where you only `select` one model.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the issue is related to the mismatch between the response model and the actual data returned from the database.
The `read_all` function is trying to return a list of Deck instances, but the `response_model` is specified as `List[DeckRead]`. Since DeckRead includes an additional field (`id`), FastAPI is expecting the response data to have this field, leading to a validation error.

Try this:

```
@router.get("/", response_model=List[Deck])
```

Comment: But `Deck` also have an id field. I've tried changing it to try but it still gives me the same answer. They both shares the same properties.